# codeigniter getting rows not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been doing a tutorial on CodeIgniter. Now I'm simply reading something from a database. I've checked the stuff I get from the db is legit. I then simply send the query result to a view called `form`. Now all I want to do in `form` is extract the stuff from the query. I get the following error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Name

Filename: views/form.php

Line Number: 36
```

Here is my controller code:

```
function index()
    {
        $data['reason'] = '';
        $this->load->model('CRUD_Model');
        $data['query']= $this->CRUD_Model->Read('tertiarystudy','Name is not NULL');
        $this->load->view('form',$data);
    }
```

Here is my view code:

```
foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        echo $row['Name'];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your model use `db->result()` or `db->result_array()` to get back the data? If it's `result()` then your rows are instances of `stdClass`. In that case, do:

```
foreach($query as $row) {
    echo $row->Name;
}
```

Comment: His model must not be used db->result() or db->result_array() because of if he use $row->Name in his view then following error has been produced..
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2):

Try with print_r result,

```
  foreach ($query as $row) {
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($row);
      echo '</pre>'; 

      // if you get result a array, format array is $row['namefield'].
      // if you get result a object, format object is $row->namefield.
      // if you not get any result, you must check code in controller n model again.
  }
```

Comment: It's good idea to debug the php code. But, It's better to debug outside the for loop. You can debug the $query.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($query);
echo '</pre>';

Or you can debug the php code using var_dump() replacement of print_r()
suppose, var_dump($query)

Comment: yup, using pre to be easily visible

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in your view..

```
foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        echo $row[0]['Name'];

    }
```

Comment: I've tried that and I get the following error A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/form.php

Line Number: 36

Comment: Note the "Name" field/property is correct. I've checked in the db, the names match

Comment: Please now check. I edited the answer. Hope this will be ok now

Comment: If not ok now please provide your model code. Have to check actually what type of data is returned by your model?

Answer (score 1):

i think this sample code is useful

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->db->select('userid');
        $some = $this->db->get('users_key',1)->result_array();
        var_dump($some);
    }

    // result_array Output
    // array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["userid"]=> string(1) "1" } } 

    // result Output
    // array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#15 (1) { ["userid"]=> string(1) "1" } } 


}
```